# Laravel get email parameter when user log in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-5

I want to make url change like `localhost:8000/{$email}`. I use `php artisan make:auth` on Laravel 5.2

But I don't know How can I do this.

please give some tips or relative pages. sorry for short english.

++

I've changed on `RedirectsUsers.php` like this:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '{$email}';

}
```

then, url is chaged. but It brings error like this : `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

routes.php

`Route::get('{$email}', 'HomeController@index');`

++

AuthController.php

`protected $redirectTo = '{$email}';`

Comment: What do you mean by URL change? Do you want them to be redirected to  `localhost:8000/[their_email]` after they log in?

Comment: @James Yes. email that user write when they're log in. I've edited my posts .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting to `/{$email}` and you made route for `{$email}`

Change your route to `/{$email}`

Also you should change variable `$redirectedTo` in LoginController inside Auth folder to redirect user after login

```
 /**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $redirectTo = '/'.\Auth::user()->email;
```

Comment: it brings `FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 36:
Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Comment: that part is `protected $redirectTo = '/'.\Auth::user()->email;`

Comment: `\Auth::user()->email` this was to get current user email , you can change code to find email

Comment: ok, if it produce fatal error you can stick with your previous approach.

Comment: previous part :: `protected $redirectTo = '{$email}';` And I changed {$email} not /{$email}. but It still brings error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Comment: did you try with `/{$email}` in all over instead just `{$email}` ?

Comment: Oh, I changed `{$email}` to `{email}` on `routes.php` . then It works. Thank you for your comments. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Made changes to the route file with the new rule

```
Route::get('/{email}', 'UserController@profile')->name('user-profile');
```

And In `AuthController.php` change the `$redirectTo`

```
/**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    Protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

To

```
Protected $redirectTo = route('user-profile/'.Auth->user()->email);
```